# How do i skip some number from number picker?

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

Number picker

```
np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    np.setMaxValue(200);
    np.setMinValue(1);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

when I scroll numbers should go 1 2 3 ... etc ..

what I want is when scrolling its should go 5 10 15 etc

how to do it ?

Comment: Can't you use the method `NumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(String[] values)` for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code snippet should fix your problem;

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
String[] numbers = new String[200/5];
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    numbers[i] = Integer.toString(i*5+5);
np.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
np.setMaxValue(numbers.length-1);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        int newValue = newVal * 5 + 5;
    }
});
```

Comment: this codes works correctly but the output is give out some other values I don’t know why , but the number picker scrolling works fine. and one more thing what should I do to stay the number picker value has it is when closing .when coming back to activity after shutting down it should be the last selected value ..

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What sort of other nos. and how did you get them? I have tested this code to some extent. Your inputs would help me fix it.

Comment: 5 shows number picker output is 1 ,10 shows number picker output is 2 etc

Comment: I'll fix it and send across to you. Its simple... It is providing the index of the displayvalues index. Need to multiply by 5 and use it.

Comment: Fixed it... please use the newValue!

Comment: I select 20 from number picker and closes app and when I come back I want that 20 in number picker , can you guide me how to do it .

Comment: Please call np.setValue((value - 5)/5) when you come back. Here 'value' would be 5, 10, 15, 20, .....

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
     picker.setValue((newVal < oldVal)?oldVal-5:oldVal+5);
 }

});
```

Also NumberPicker in Android has a method called [setDisplayedValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

```
String[] minuteValues = new String[12];

for (int i = 0; i < minuteValues.length; i++) {
    String number = Integer.toString(i*5);
    minuteValues[i] = number.length() < 2 ? "0" + number : number;
}

numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(minuteValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NumberPicker.Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.Formatter.html) to format display values.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469826/796231)

Comment: Everything fine expect that numberPicker.setValue() does not work properly in this approach.