# How to customize value for numbers in NumberPicker in android?

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I have a number picker for setting a data limit in MB. right now, I have numberPicker, contains numeric values in sequence like [1,2,3,....., 2000 MB].

But I want a numberPicker that should contain numeric values like [100,200,300,...., 2000MB].
How can I do this?

Comment: show some code to help more

Comment: I think you can find a solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979643/change-the-step-size-of-a-numberpicker

Comment: You can use array to display your customized values. Check this link >> http://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-numberpicker-in-android.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Displayed array values for your picker

```
int NUMBER_OF_VALUES = 20; //num of values in the picker
int PICKER_RANGE = 100;
...
String[] displayedValues  = new String[NUMBER_OF_VALUES];
//Populate the array
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++)
    displayedValues[i] = String.valueOf(PICKER_RANGE * (i+1));
/* OR: if the array is easy to be hard-coded, then just hard-code it:
   String[] displayedValues = {"100", "200", "300", .....}; */
```

Set arr in your picker :

```
numPicker.setMinValue(0); 
numPicker.setMaxValue(displayedValues.size()-1);
numPicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues);
```

get/set the value of the picker :

```
//To get the current value in the picker
choosenValue = displayedValues[numPicker.getValue()]; 
//To set a new value (let's say 150)
for( int i=0; i<displayedValues.length ; i++ )
    if( displayedValues[i].equals("300") )
         numPicker.setValue(i);
```

Comment: can we set Integer array instead of string array?

Comment: means show me your array you have to put in picker?

Comment: see this link :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29

on  void setDisplayedValues(String[] value) you are not set int[]

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
int start = 100;
        String[] numbers = new String[20];
        for(int i =0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
            numbers[i] = start + "";
            start = start + 100;
        }
        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.id_number_picker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(20);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String[] nums = new String[21];
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = Integer.toString((i+1)*100);
        }

numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMinValue(19);
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```