# Make selected numberpicker choice not available next time

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have two numberpicker and a submit button. I like to fade out or something like that when a value is selected and submit button is clicked.

So if number 20 is selected it will not be available next time.

Is this possible with Android numberpicker?

Comment: you will have to manually record, which values were already selected, and disable and enable the button depending on that.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I will try this solution out :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread, on how to customize values of a NumberPicker in Android:
[How to customize value for numbers in NumberPicker in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585648/how-to-customize-value-for-numbers-in-numberpicker-in-android)

Once you know how to customize values it is trivial. On the item selected event (or in your case on click of "submit button") remove the value from the list of the custom values and update the NumberPicker.

Comment: i dont want to remove the value, just fade it out :)

Comment: well, then, keep the selected values in a different list.