# TimePicker with 30 minute interval not working

Tags: android, intervals, timepicker, numberpicker

I am working on a android application and i want to set the timepicker interval to 30 minutes instead of 1 minute by default. This is my code:

```
private void setTimePickerIntervalZeroThirtyMinutes(TimePicker timePicker) {
        int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 30;
        NumberPicker minutePicker = timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android"));
        minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
        minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) + 28);
        List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
            displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
        }
        minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));
    }
```

If I run the above function, it displays the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=30
        at android.widget.NumberPicker.updateInputTextView(NumberPicker.java:1990)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(NumberPicker.java:1554)
```

I need to mention that I want to set the min value to 0 and the max value to 30, because otherwise the app won't save the data correctly to the database. Bot when I do that, it gives me the error that i have shown to you. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13475169/3426825

Comment: @homerun I've tried your solution, but it doesn't work. It gives me a similar error which i have told in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is found to be in the loop construction.

- loop construct : `i = 0`
- first loop: i += 30 `(i = 30)`
- second loop: i += 30 `(i = 60)`
- 60 < 60  = **false** `(exit loop)`

therefore your array has only 2 indexes and you trying to access something that does not exist. that is why you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know what is the problem based on your last answer you provided. However, I don't know how to put the condition in for loop to get the "00" and "30" values to be displayed in the number picker. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue. Thank you again for your help @homerun!